# JavaScript regex to replace all numbers with percentage sign

Tags: javascript, regex

I have to remove all numbers with percentage sign in string.

For instance,

```
str = "test 12% test" -> "test test"
str = "test 12 % test" -> "test test"
str = "test 12%   test" -> "test test"
str = "test 1.2% test" -> "test test"
```

For now I cannot figure out how to fix the last one - it is number with dot. My current regexp is like this:

```
name = name.replace(/\d+ ?% ?/g, "");
```

**ADDITIONAL SCENARIOS**

```
str = "test 1.2%,test" -> "test ,test" // space is optional after %
str = "test (1.2%) test" -> "test test" // space is optional after %
str = "test 1.2%" -> "test" or "test " // space could be left after test if easier
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an optional non capturing group `(?:\.\d+)?` which checks for a dot and one or more digits. At the end your could add `*` to match zero or more whitespaces.

**Explanation**

- Match optional parenthesis `\(?`
- Match one or more digits `\d+`
- Optional non capturing group to match a dot and one or more digits `(?:\.\d+)?`
- Match an optional space `?`
- Match a percentage sign `%`
- Match an optional closing parenthises `\)`
- Match zero or more whitespaces `*`

[`\(?\d+(?:\.\d+)? ?%\)? *`](https://regex101.com/r/zjxgiz/1)

```js
var strings = [
  "test 12% test",
  "test 12 % test",
  "test 12%   test",
  "test 1.2% test",
  "test 1.2%,test",
  "test (1.2%) test",
  "test 1.2%"
];

for (var i = 0; i < strings.length; i++) {
  console.log(strings[i] + "-> " + strings[i].replace(/\(?\d+(?:\.\d+)? ?%\)? */g, ""));
}
```

Comment: How this is better than above answer? And btw I forgot to mention that spcae after % is not required as sometimes comma could be there or anything. I cannot fix this.hh

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `[]` square brackets to specify a group to match.

here we are using

- `\d` : digit
- `\.`: literal `.`
- `\s`: whitespace

```js
const strings  = [
  "test 12% test",
  "test 12 % test",
  "test 12%   test",
  "test 1.2% test",
  "test   whitespace",
  "test 12 test",
  "test 1.2%,test",
  "test (1.2%) test",
  "test 1.2%",
]

strings.forEach(
  string => 
    console.log(string, string.replace(/\s\(?[\d\.\s]+\%\)?\s*/g, ' ').trim())
)
```

```html
<script src="https://codepen.io/synthet1c/pen/KyQQmL.js"></script>
```

Comment: Space after % is not required. FOr instance, sometimes there could be a comma.

Comment: You really should get your requirements before asking the question to make it easier on everybody. I have updated the answer to meet your new requirements.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that cases.

Answer (score 0):

This will get your output

Find `[^\S\r\n]*(?:\d+(?:\.\d*)?|\.\d+)\s*%[^\S\r\n]*`
Replace

https://regex101.com/r/EcbAXV/1

Formatted

```
 [^\S\r\n]*                    # Trim horizontal whitespace
 (?:                           # Valid number formats to find
      \d+ 
      (?: \. \d* )?
   |  \. \d+ 
 )
 \s*                           # Optional whitespace
 %                             # Literal percent
 [^\S\r\n]*                    # Trim horizontal whitespace
```